# How to set $_SERVER[' '] variables when running phpunit tests through Jenkins

Tags: php, ant, phpunit, jenkins

I am trying to write unit tests for an application where a lot of code changes is not possible. Almost all the .php files in the code base uses some $_SERVER[''] variables like

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mainApi.php';
```

So now when I have to write and run PHPUnit test cases I have to somehow set these variables. 
At present I am setting these variables in the user environment and then doing

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT');
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mainApi.php';
```

Getting the server variables like this is working fine. I run my tests through commandline as `$ phpunit test.php`.

**Ques1:** Is it possible to set the $_SERVER variables while running the phpunit tests through commandline?

I also have to run these unit tests through Jenkins and I am not able to set these server variable through ANT/build file.

**Ques2:** Is it possible to set these variable through ant build file in Jenkins or by running any shell script before executing the phpunit tests through Jenkins?

I tried exporting the server variable through a shell script

```
    export DOCUMENT_ROOT=/server/path-to-root-dir
```

and calling that script in the build.xml in Jenkins

```
<export name="setEnv" description="set server var">
    <exec executable="sh">
       <arg value = "sumit.sh" />
    </exec> 
</target>
```

but its not working. Is there any setting that I can do for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about #1, but PHPUnit itself would have to support it. I don't see any way to do that via the command line. However, if you put your current workaround into `bootstrap.php` you don't have to do it in each test.

For #2, [`<exec>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) allows you to set environment variables using nested `<env>` elements. I use this in Jenkins.

```
<exec executable="phpunit" ...>
    <env key="DOCUMENT_ROOT" value="/var/www/php"/>
</exec>
```

**Update:** You typically create `bootstrap.php` to setup add the source directory to the include path and initialize the test environment however you need. This file isn't supplied by PHPUnit--unlike `phpunit.xml`.

I place it in the same directory as `phpunit.xml`, but that's because I have a separate file for each project. It goes in the directory that holds your tests typically. This allows you to run `phpunit` from the command-line without telling it how to find those configuration files. Otherwise you have to use `--bootstrap` and/or `--configuration` to point to them.

Here is how I structure a typical project:

```
<project-root>/
    build.xml
    src/
        MyClass.php
    test/
        MyClassTest.php
        phpunit.xml
        bootstrap.php
```

Comment: can we set `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` directly through build file? Your method `<env key="DOCUMENT_ROOT" value="/path" />` works perfectly fine but I have so many SERVER variables in my code that I will have to write all the `$_SERVER[] = getenv()` in a php file and will have to import that file in all the test classes. Is there a way that we can reduce it?

Comment: @Sumitk - You can do the assignments in `bootstrap.php` that PHPUnit loads automatically before running any tests. Either place the file in the directory at the root of your tests or point PHPUnit at it using the `--bootstrap` command-line argument.

Comment: Is this `bootstrap.php` a file that we create along with the test files or does it come with PHPUnit? Coz I cant see it on my system. Also if we create it, where should I place it? with all the test files or with the `phpunit.xml.dist'?

Comment: You create it, typically to set up your include path and initialize the test environment. See my update.