# CakePHP 3: Set $_SERVER variable for unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

I need to be able to set a `$_SERVER[]` variable in my unit test to several different values. I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6934951/1743903), but that only allows me to have 1 value, and I need to test multiple values.

I get the sense from the CakePHP documentation that it has something to do with `$this->configRequest()`, but that's just a hunch at this point.

Comment: You shouldn't fiddle with superglobals directly in CakePHP, so, yeah, generally `configRequest()` is likely the way to go if you don't want to / can't set things via phpunit. Any specific problems with its usage? What exactly do you need to set? And where do you need have it available  - in controller/integration tests?

Comment: I have apache parse user certificates and set some of the data in the $_SERVER variable so I can programmatically authenticate users. An example is `$_SERVER['SSL_AUTHORITY']`. I want to be able to access it my controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
$this->configRequest([                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        'environment' => [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            'HTTP_REFERER' => 'foo',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    ]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the global variables directliy in your test function like this:

```
$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'multipart/form-data';
```

Or lets say to simulate a ajax-request:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

But this is unclean.

Better is to use

```
$this->request->env('REQUEST_METHOD', 'POST');
```

Documented here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#environment-variables-from-server-and-env